# Django: Strange import error

Tags: python, django

I'm deploying a (proprietary) Django application (with bad support ;-)). The only thing I need to do is setup a new Django project and implement the app's urls. So my url config is as follows:

```
  1 from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
  2 
  3 urlpatterns = patterns('',
  4     url(r'^', include('ap01.urls')),
  5 )
```

The application in question is also added to my INSTALLED_APPS setting.

I can validate (./manage.py validate) and all is good. When running the app I get the following import error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named ap01.urls
```

The module is present in the Python Path reported by Django and when manually importing the urls module everything works, ie:

```
./manage.py shell 
__import__('ap01.urls')
```

I compared setups with the QA and dev servers and everything seems be in place correctly. The only thing that differs is the Python version (2.6 on QA and dev; 2.7 on this new machine).

Comment: 1. Is ap01 in your settings INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, it is. Adding info to my question, thanks :)

Comment: Well I didn't change it if that's what you mean. Just a blank django project using the urls of ap01.

Comment: Don't assume the `PYTHONPATH` is the same for the shell and your deployment environment.

Comment: The PYTHONPATH reported by the Django error page is correct, it contains the ap01 module. It's actually symlinked to python2.7/dist-packages so it's definitely there.

Comment: Similar issue I have experienced when my app had permissions limited, it worked fine from shell and runserver but not quite in mod_wsgi, so maybe that.

Answer (score 2):

I would debug this like this:

You need to know where the ImportError gets raised. Then add something like this:

```
import sys
raise Exception(sys.path)
```

- Is the directory above "ap01" in sys.path?
- Does the directory ap01 contain a `__init__.py` file?
- What user-id has you python interpreter (the one which raises the import exception)? Try: `import os, sys; assert False, (os.getuid(), sys.path)`
- Maybe this user-id has not enough permission to read the file? Get this user with "su" (if you use a unix like OS) and then try to read it: `less ...../ap01/...py`